# Получаю ошибку при применении миграций

Tags: python, django, миграция

пишу `python3 manage.py makemigrations` и получаю

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/makemigrations.py:105: RuntimeWarning: Got an error checking a consistent migration history performed for database connection 'default': could not connect to server: No such file or directory
        Is the server running locally and accepting
        connections on Unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"?

  warnings.warn(
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django_currentuser/db/models/fields.py:57: UserWarning: You passed an argument to CurrentUserField that will be ignored. Avoid args and following kwargs: default, null, to.
  warnings.warn(self.warning)
No changes detected
```

я новичок в django, перевести - перевел ошибку, но как ее решить не понимаю, буду рад любой помощи

**CurrentUserField**

```
import warnings

from django.conf import settings
from django.db import models
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _
from django_currentuser.middleware import get_current_authenticated_user


class CurrentUserField(models.ForeignKey):

    warning = ("You passed an argument to CurrentUserField that will be "
               "ignored. Avoid args and following kwargs: default, null, to.")
    description = _(
        'as default value sets the current logged in user if available')
    defaults = dict(null=True, default=get_current_authenticated_user,
                    to=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.on_update = kwargs.pop("on_update", False)
        self._warn_for_shadowing_args(*args, **kwargs)

        if "on_delete" not in kwargs:
            kwargs["on_delete"] = models.CASCADE

        if self.on_update:
            kwargs["editable"] = False
            kwargs["blank"] = True

        kwargs.update(self.defaults)
        super(CurrentUserField, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def deconstruct(self):
        name, path, args, kwargs = super(CurrentUserField, self).deconstruct()
        if self.on_update:
            kwargs['on_update'] = self.on_update
            del kwargs["editable"]
            del kwargs["blank"]

        return name, path, args, kwargs

    def pre_save(self, model_instance, add):
        if self.on_update:
            value = get_current_authenticated_user()
            if value is not None:
                value = value.pk
            setattr(model_instance, self.attname, value)
            return value
        else:
            return super(CurrentUserField, self).pre_save(model_instance, add)

    def _warn_for_shadowing_args(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if args:
            warnings.warn(self.warning)
        else:
            for key in set(kwargs).intersection(set(self.defaults.keys())):
                if not kwargs[key] == self.defaults[key]:
                    warnings.warn(self.warning)
                    break
```

Всем спасибо

Comment: команда `makemigration` не смогла присоединиться к БД. Команда работает таким образом, что сравнивает БД с моделями. Если  модели и таблицы в БД расходятся, то команда создает миграции, чтоб таблицы привести в соответствие с моделями. Проверьте настройки соединения с БД в settings и запущен ли сервер по тому адресу и порту, какие указаны в настройках.

Comment: @RomanKonoval ,
я пофиксил 2ю ошибку - в настройках проекта 

`AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'companies.User'` я изменил `User` на `user` и ошибка исчезла, сейчас надо разобраться с первой ошибкой, с подключением к серверу

Comment: пока с терминалом и homebrew вожусь, чтоб по этому гайду что-нибудь сделать https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/shell/could+not+connect+to+server%3A+No+such+file+or+directory+Is+the+server+running+locally+and+accepting+connections+on+Unix+domain+socket+%22%2Ftmp%2F.s.PGSQL.5432%22%3F

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка 1 - с помощью homebrew в терминале я установил postgresql с помощью такой команды `brew install postgresql`

Ошибка 2 - в настройках проекта `AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'companies.User'` я изменил User на user и ошибка исчезла

Answer (score 0):

Позвольте тоже рассказать - как решил вопрос с error

> RuntimeWarning: Got an error checking a consistent migration history performed for database connection 'default':

или

> django.db.utils.OperationalError

ДЕнь добрый.
Поймал её на самом старте работ (models.py прописаны,)
`python manage.py makemigretions` прошли гладко.
`python manage.py migrate*` поймал error

И так
Файл `settings.py` > `DATABASES` > *мои данные, в * `USER` и `PASSWORD` брал из `.env` файла.
Пароль и логин перепутал местами и не видел этого.